# How to program a click panel for chemical elements (like a periodic table)?

Tags: programming, dynamic, replacement, curated-data, chemistry

The command

```
ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]
```

indicates `RGBColor`s of atoms by clicking a panel.

As I don't want to reinvent the wheel, I asked myself:

How do I transform `ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]` into a click panel for chemical elements, which could be used as an argument for other functions like `ElementData[]` or `IsotopeData[]`?

Comment: What is the question?  If this is not a question but instead intended to be instructional for others please edit the post to make it a question (it can be very simple) then post the majority of this as a self-answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thx, I followed your suggestions, and brought it in Q&A form.

Comment: You will notice that you already have a combined four votes. :-)

Answer (score 11):

### simple version

With a single codeline, `ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"]`, can be transformed in a click panel for `ElementData[]`.

```
{ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] // 
  ReplaceAll[#, RuleDelayed[ "MouseClicked", $_] :> 
   (RuleDelayed["MouseClicked", 
      atomClicked = Part[RuleDelayed["MouseClicked", $], 
       2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]])] &, 
 Dynamic[atomClicked, Initialization :> (atomClicked = "H")]
}
```

[image: simple click panel for periodic table]

### changing size or removing panel

Now it would be nice to change the panel size.This could be done simply by using

`... // Magnify[#, 2] &`

but maybe not the best solution.Therefore I added another function, which replaces `ImageSize` in `Graphics`.

```
(*version2 >>> shows how to remove the panel and how to change image size*)
Clear@"`*"
atomClicked = "H";(*init>>>important*)
imageSize[size_] := 
 ReplaceAll[#, 
   Graphics[x_, {y__}] :> Graphics[x, {ImageSize -> size, y}]] &;
atomClickedFunction = 
  ReplaceAll[#, 
    RuleDelayed[
      "MouseClicked", $_] :> (RuleDelayed["MouseClicked", 
       atomClicked = 
        Part[RuleDelayed["MouseClicked", $], 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]])] &;
{ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] // atomClickedFunction // imageSize@600 //
      First (*removes Panel*), atomClicked, 
    ElementData[atomClicked, "AlternateStandardNames" (* >>>
     Latin names,
     only for Latin abbreviations available in ElementData[]*)], 
    ElementData[atomClicked, "AtomicNumber"], 
    ElementData[atomClicked, "StandardName"], 
    ElementData[atomClicked, "DiscoveryYear"], 
    ElementData[atomClicked, "DiscoveryCountries"]} // Column // 
  Framed // Dynamic
```

[image: a clickPanel for ElementData[ ] now]

Transformed in a clickPanel for `ElementData[ ]` now.

Implementing the code in form of a `Module[]` with `optionPatterns` and more ... could be the next step  ...

Just an idea ...

Answer (score 9):

I recently needed to do something like this. Here's a simplified version of what I came up with:

```
DynamicModule[{elem = "Hydrogen"}, 
              Panel[Row[{(ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. 
              HoldPattern["MouseClicked" :> rhs_] :> ("MouseClicked" :> (elem = 
              CanonicalName[ElementData[Cases[Unevaluated[rhs], _Rule, ∞][[1, 1]]]]))) /. 
              g_Graphics :> Append[g, ImageSize -> Large] /.
              Panel[stuff_, __] :> stuff, Spacer[20], 
              Dynamic[Grid[Transpose[{Style[#, Bold] & /@
                           {"name:", "symbol:", "atomic number:", "atomic weight:",
                            "phase:", "electron configuration:"}, 
                           Table[ElementData[elem, prop],
                                 {prop, {"Name", "Symbol", "AtomicNumber", "AtomicWeight",
                                         "Phase", "ElectronConfigurationString"}}] /.
                           {e_EntityClass :> ToLowerCase[CanonicalName[e]], 
                            m_Missing :> ToLowerCase[First[m]], 
                            q_Quantity :> QuantityMagnitude[q]}}], Alignment -> Left], 
                      TrackedSymbols :> {elem}]}]]]
```

[image: interactive periodic table]

Comment: Very nice! The answer reminds me of the chemical knowledge I learned in high school seven years ago. Especially, the priority of `3d>4s` that about electron configuration.

Comment: @J.M. beautiful, useful and instructive (Mma wise). :)