# Nested parameter selecting in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, data, filtering

I have the following code, stripped down from the original to the bare essentials:

```
numbers = Range@30;

Manipulate[Plot[a x^2 - b x^.3 + c x - d, {x, 0, 10}]

 , Grid[{
   {"a", "b", "c", "d"}
   , {Control[{{a, numbers[[3]], ""}, numbers, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]
    , Control[{{b, numbers[[5]], ""}, numbers, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]
    , Control[{{c, numbers[[7]], ""}, numbers, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]
    , Control[{{d, numbers[[9]], ""}, numbers, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]}
   }, Dividers -> {{2 -> True, 3 -> True, 4 -> True}, None}]
 ]
```

This looks like this:

[image]

All is working fine, however, the selection is clumsy, as I have the same selection pane four times. This might even get clumsier in the original, with more selections, and maybe even many more than four times.
What I would like to have is the following (a pure mockup that is not working as I wish and describe below):

[image]

This should work as follow:
Select a variable, e.g. b. Then select the parameter, in this case a number, for b, e.g. 5, using the number pane underneath. Then select another variable, e.g. c and select a number for this variable using the same number pane underneath, etc.
In the actual version, the silly number pane will be replaced by a periodic table of elements, and elements are selected for various data presentation.

Addition--------
I probably should have made a more concrete example. So here is a stripped down version much closer to what I try to achieve:

```
data = {
   {"Mg", 3, 4, 2, 5}
   , {"Si", 6, 4, 7, 2}
   , {"Al", 2, 5, 2, 6}
   , {"Sr", 1, 5, 7, 8}
   };

a = Sort[ElementData[#, "AtomicNumber"] & /@ Range[40]];
elementsSorted = ElementData[#, "Symbol"] & /@ a;

Manipulate[
 posEl1 = Position[data, el1][[1, 1]];
 posEl2 = Position[data, el2][[1, 1]];
 posEl3 = Position[data, el3][[1, 1]];
 ListPlot[
  Transpose[{Rest@data[[posEl1]], 
    Rest@data[[posEl2]]/Rest@data[[posEl3]]}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}]

 , Grid[{
   {"x-Axis", "y-Axis nom", "y-Axis denom"}
   , {Control[{{el1, elementsSorted[[12]], ""}, elementsSorted, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]
    , Control[{{el2, elementsSorted[[14]], ""}, elementsSorted, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]
    , Control[{{el3, elementsSorted[[38]], ""}, elementsSorted, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
      Appearance -> "Horizontal" -> {Automatic, 6}}]}
   }, Dividers -> {{2 -> True, 3 -> True}, None}]
 ]
```

The result looks as shown below.
As the very reduced dataset only includes 4 elements, only those can be selected to make the plot work.
Now, what would be great is, to have a periodic table instead of the pane (actually this is what I would get working). The important bit is to have only one periodic table, and a selector as shown above, for which axis/nominator/denominator I want to select the element.

[image]

Comment: I guess four integer `Manipulator[]` controls does not fit the actual use-case?  E.g., `{a, 1, 30, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}` etc.  (Just checking, because the selector-type controls make the problem seem complicated, to the point of possible needing a custom control.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. It is not important what controls are used. The main thing is to first select for which parameter (a,b,c or d) a variable (in this case a number) is chosen, then choose the actual value. Then do the same with the next variable.

Comment: Wouldn't 4 sliders accomplish that?: The user picks which slider to move (a, b, c, or d) and then chooses the actual value by moving the slider.

Comment: I see your point. The thing is that this is a simplified example. Ultimately, I would want to use a periodic table or else instead of some plain numbers. So imagine a periodic table instead of the number pane.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55273)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Second try

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{x, yNum, yDen},
  {x, yNum, yDen} = {"x-Axis", "y-Axis num", "y-Axis den"} /. data;
  Pane["<your stuff here>"[x, yNum, yDen], {400, 100}]
  ],
 
 (* selector for axis categories *)
 {{axis, "x-Axis", "select"}, {"x-Axis", "y-Axis num", "y-Axis den"}, 
  SetterBar[
    Dynamic[axis, (axis = #; axiselement = Lookup[data, axis]) &], 
    First@#2, ##3] &},
 Row[{
   ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. e_EventHandler :>
     (e /. {HoldPattern["MouseClicked" :> _] :>  (* replace mouse-click action *)
         ("MouseClicked" :> (axiselement = atomName[e]; data[axis] = axiselement)),
        r_Rectangle :>                           (* add dynamic style to elements *)
         {Dynamic[
           If[axiselement === atomName[e],
            {EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]], Opacity[0.6], r},
            {EdgeForm[None], r}
            ]]}})
   }],
 
 (* local variables *)
 {{axiselement, "Mg"}, None},  (* should be initialized to data[axis] *)
 {{data, (* data base for selected categories (axis) *)
   AssociationThread[{"x-Axis", "y-Axis num", "y-Axis den"} -> {"Mg", "Si", "Sr"}]}, None},
 
 (* options *)
 TrackedSymbols :> {data},
 Initialization :>   (* could add initialization of axis, axiselement, data *)
  (atomName[e_EventHandler] := First@Cases[e, Style[name_String, ___] :> name, Infinity, 1])
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### First try

Probably too complicated, but also too cool (imho): Click on element at top. Move the slider to change its value in the table below.

```
Manipulate[
 datadisplay /. data,
 Dynamic[
  ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. 
   e_EventHandler :> (e /. HoldPattern[
        "MouseClicked" :> _] :> 
          ("MouseClicked" :> (key = atomName[e]; value = Lookup[data, key])))
  ],
 {{key, "H"}, None},
 {{value, 0, Dynamic@key}, 0, 5, 1,
   Manipulator[Dynamic[value, (value = data[key] = #) &], ##2, Appearance -> "Labeled"] &},
 {{data, Association@ Thread[ColorData["Atoms", "ColorRules"][[All, 1]] -> 0]}, None},
 {{datadisplay, ColorData["Atoms", "Panel"] /. e_EventHandler :> First[e]}, None},
 TrackedSymbols :> {data},
 Initialization :>
  (atomName[e_EventHandler] :=
     First@Cases[e, Style[name_String, ___] :> name, Infinity, 1])
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Explanation coming...unless it's totally wrong.

Comment: It is cool – but not fully what I try to achieve. I made an edit to my initial question with a more concrete example. Anyway – thanks so far!

Comment: In the first version of the question, I interpreted a, b, c, d to represent the elements, which I see is wrong; now it seems they represent the axis/num/.den. (i.e., which category is chosen first), and there are only three choices instead of four -- is that right?

Comment: The number of choices should be flexible, I.e. 3, 4, or even more.

Comment: As I understand it, then, you want a control that depends on a control that depends on another control (element selector dep. on choice of axis/etc. selector dep. on a control for the choices).  I've shown how a control can depend on another control, maybe it's enough of a start?

Comment: This looks fantastic! Thanks! I have to work my way through the code, though, quite some stuff I don't use frequently – or have never used. The number of choices should be flexible, I.e. 3, 4, or even more. But I think (hope), I should be able to adjust this in the code.

Comment: Ignore the comment shortly before This was by accident. As long as I can paste anything into the Pane filed, all is perfect.

Comment: I guess you've seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55273) already... ;)

Comment: @J.M. Oops, nope. Not that I recall. I thought to search "periodic table" in the docs only just to see. It was just the sort of thing you might find in a ~6GB application, augmented by web data. I was surprised it was already clickable. I was hoping only for a layout I could commandeer.

Comment: @J.M. No, I haven't seen this. Looks nice!